# How to make AR( augmented reality) in unity2018?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Well, i tried to use vuforia but I did not succeed, there is a better way to make A AR (augmented reality) in unity2018?

Comment: Maybe look at Zappar outside of Unity.  Could be easier and quicker

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you had no success in Vuforia, it is one of the most refined SDK for AR.

You can still try other SDK-s, for exapmle: [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/) or [MaxstAR](http://maxst.com/#/).

Both of these SDKs have pretty good sample projects, so it would be easier for bigginer.